# Measuring code coverage java using protractor e2e test

Tags: java, angular, protractor, code-coverage, e2e-testing

There are a two projects one of them is written java is a backend code one of them is angular typescript frontend codes. i wrote e2e tests in the frontend project. now i want to measuring backend code coverage using this e2e test please help

Answer (score 0):

Code Coverage is a measurement of how many lines/blocks/arcs of your code are executed while the automated tests are running.

Search online code coverage tools that can help you, protractor is just end to end testing tool, you need another tool for code coverage.

Comment: i didnt mean that, i mean i wrote e2e test using protractor now i want to use jacoco or sonarqube to measur code coverage but i dont know how to use them together

Answer (score 0):

At a high level,

1. Instrument cli generated main.js file with grunt protractor coverage
2. Deploy this as part of your build

   Run Protractor tests on the application

   Capture coverage for each spec via a collector port

   Consolidate spec json files with remapIstanbul

   Generate report

The devil is in the details :-)

https://github.com/r3b/grunt-protractor-coverage